# Circuit for Charging 3.7V Lithium Polymer battery with Arduino Nano's 5V output

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, tp4056

I am building a circuit that charges a Lithium Polymer Battery with Arduino Nano IoT's 5V output. The idea is simple: while I connect USB to Arduino Nano, it starts charging the battery through TP4056. When disconnecting the USB, the battery powers Arduino Nano.

I have created a circuit, and it seems to work fine. However, I would like to clarify if there are any potential problems or issues with this circuit. Since I do not have an engineering background, I have developed this circuit through trial and error.

I have attached a hand-drawn diagram and a breadboarding example of what I have done so far.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]